# Showing that the extension $1 \to C_3 \to C_6 \to C_2 \to 1$ is split by finding complement of $C_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Show that the extension $1 \to C_3 \to C_6 \to C_2 \to 1$ is split but the extension $1 \to C_2 \to C_4 \to C_2 \to 1$ is not split.

I think one way to show that an exact sequence $1 \to N \to G \to Q \to 1$ is split is to construct a valid traversal function $\tau: Q \to G$ which is a group homomorphism. The other way is to show that $N$ has a complement in $G$. I'm trying to follow the second method here.

### My attempt

**Showing $1 \to C_3 \to C_6 \to C_2 \to 1$ is split**

Let $C_2 = \{e, a\}$ where $a$ is a generator of $C_2$.

Let $C_3 = \{e, b, b^2\}$ where $b$ is a generator of $C_3$.

I need to show that $C_3$ has a complement in $C_6$ which is isomorphic to $C_2$ (?).

Also, we know that the product of two subgroups $S$ and $T$ is a group if and only if $ST = TS$. But I'm stuck here, i.e., when trying to show that $C_2C_3 = C_3C_2$.

$$C_2C_3 = \{e, b, b^2, a, ab, ab^2\}$$

$$C_3C_2 = \{e, a, b, ba, b^2, b^2a\}$$

The elements $e, a, b, b^2$ are common in both the sets. But then, how do I show that $ab=ba$ or $ab = b^2a$?

Comment: $C_6$ is an abelian group, is it not?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. Am I missing something obvious? (I'm really new to this and am not a math major, so please bear with me if I did something silly.)

Comment: @Arthur I mean my point was merely about the "set products" $C_2C_3$ (and $C_3C_2$) and not about the cyclic abelian "group" $C_6$. So I'm not sure if I can directly conclude $ab =ba$ from here.

Comment: There is a group that is a non-split extension of $C_3$ by $C_2$ in which you do **not** get $ab=ba$, namely $S_3$. So there is no hope to do what you are trying to do, in the abstract. You **have** to use that you are working with $C_6$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Note that we still have $C_3C_2 = C_2C_3$ in that case, however, as then $ab = b^2a$.

Comment: @Arthur:, yes of course we do, because the copy of $C_3$ is normal, and because the product is a group. But the point is that you cannot “prove”, in the *abstract*, that when you have a group that is a product of a copy of $C_3$ by a copy of $C_2$, then the two generators will commute. They don’t necessarily do.

Comment: Even without trying to prove $ab = ba$, however, they both have six distinct elements, and they are both subsets of your $C_6$. So they _have_ to be equal, since there is no room for them to be different. @ArturoMagidin That is true.

Comment: @Arthur How are you able to say that "there is no room for them to be different"? Could you please elaborate on that (perhaps in an answer)?

Comment: @S.D. How many subsets of 6 elements are there in a set of 6 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn’t work as you seem to hope. For one thing, $C_2$ is given as a quotient of $C_6$; you would need to define a map from $C_2$ to $C_6$ in order to talk about the image of $a$ in $C_6$.

But in order to do that you must first define the splitting function, which is what you want to do in the first place. So I don’t see you hope to do what you want to do. Note that there is a group that is a non-split extension of $C_3$ by $C_2$, in which $ab$ is not going to equal $ba$; namely, $S_3$. So what you are trying to do just isn’t going to work.

You have to use the fact that you are working with $C_6$ (and later, with $C_4$).

If $C_6 = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$, then there are only two possible images for $b$; and there is only one possible image for $a$ if you are going to have a group morphism. You should be able to take it from there.

In contrast, with $C_4=\{1,y,y^2,y^3\}$, there is only one possible splitting for $C_2$, but that does not yield a complement to the only possible image of $C_2$.

Comment: If my splitting function (in the $C_6$ case) is say $f$ and I define $f(a) = \{x^1, x^3, x^5\}$ and $f(e) = \{x^0, x^2, x^4\}$ would $f$ be a valid group homomorphism? And if say $g$ maps from $C_3$ to $C_6$, would $g(e) = \{x^0, x^3\}$, $g(b) = \{x^1, x^4\}$ and $g(b^2) = \{x^2, x^5\}$ be a valid homomorphism? Or alternatively, I guess you meant $g(b) = \{x^2, x^5\}$ while $g(b^2) = \{x^1, x^4\}$? Is that what you mean by "there are two possible images for $b$"?

Comment: @S.D. A splitting function is a map from $C_2$ to $C_6$. It should take elements to **elements**. Mapping $a$ to a subset is nonsense.

Comment: @S.D. When you map $C_3$ to $C_6$, you have to send the generator of $C_3$ to an element of order $3$ in $C_6$. But $C_6$ has two elements of order $3$, so there are two possibliities for the image of $b$ in map $\iota\colon C_3\to C_6$.

Comment: @S.D. You mean, would it be possible for me to write out the complete solution instead of helping you figure this out? Yes, it would, and if I were inclined to do so I would have done it to begin with. Again: you have to define a function from $C_2$ to $C_6$. That means that the generator of $C_2$ has to map to an element of $C_6$ that satisfies $g^2=e$. There are only two such elements, and one of them is $e$. Is it really that hard to figure out what you need to do here?

Comment: A couple of confusions: 1. Why exactly should the splitting function have to send the generator of $C_3$ to an element of order 3 in $C_6$ and why should the other function you mention have to send the generator of $C_2$ to an order $2$ element in $C_6$? 2. You said that there is only *one* possible image for $a$ (for a mapping from $C_2$ to $C_6$) but in your comments you say that there are *two* elements of $C_6$ that satisfy $g^2=e$. I'm sure I'm appearing quite dumb right now, and also that you did try to help me, but I guess I'll ask it anyway to clear up my confusions in this topic.

Comment: @S.D. The splitting function comes from $C_2$, not $C_3$. The image of the generator of $C_3$ must be an element of order $3$ because the first map in a short exact sequence must be one-to-one, *by definition of “short exact sequence”*. The splitting function goes from $C_2$ to $C_6$, and it must map the generator to an element of order $2$ because, **by definition** (again!) the splitting function for $g$ must be a map $f$ such that $gf=\mathrm{id}_{C_2}$, and if a composition is injective, then the first map must be injective. (cont)

Comment: @S.D. As to your final question: I explicitly said what the issue was. Though there are two elements that satisfy $g^2=e$, that is not the same as two elements of order $2$; it’s two elements of order **dividing** $2$, and I *explicitly* told you that one of the two elements is the identity, which does not have order $2$, it has order $1$. So the identity cannot be the element you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, Arturo. I think I understand the whole of your answer now after your clarifications in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The two sets $C_2C_3$ and $C_3C_2$ both have $6$ elements, and they are both subsets of $C_6$, which also has $6$ elements. So all three of these sets have to be equal.

Comment: Minor confusion: how can we say that $C_2C_3$ is a subset of $C_6$? I mean I know it for a fact that $S$ and $T$ are subsets of group $G$ then their product is also a subset of $G$, but I don't know the proof.

Comment: @S.D. It follows pretty directly from the fact that the group operation is required to be closed: Any element of $ST$ is the product of an element of $S$ and an element of $T$. These are also both elements of $G$ (since $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $G$), and thus their product is in $G$.